# Mysql Query to find last datetime each user have successfully logged in

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables "creds" and "logadm". In "creds" are "users" and in "logadm" are stored records of their login to website. Here is the structure:

```
table creds
-----------
id  username    password
1   vasek       12345
2   roman       12345
3   jan         12345

table logadm
------------
id  user    ip          datum                   prihl
41  vasek   127.0.0.1   2017-06-21 10:50:19     1
40  roman   127.0.0.1   2017-06-21 10:49:50     0
39  vasek   127.0.0.1   2017-06-21 10:49:36     1
...
```

I have query which shows every user and their datetime of last login. (Also users who havent logged in yet):

```
SELECT username,MAX(logadm.datum) datum
FROM creds
LEFT JOIN logadm
ON username = user
GROUP BY username
```

Output:

```
Name    Last login
jan 
roman   2017-06-21 10:49:50
vasek   2017-06-21 10:50:19
```

**I would like to show all users and for each user that exists show their last successfull login.** Every row of "logadm" has in "prihl" column 0 or 1. 1 means that login was successfull and 0 means that not - wrong "username" or "password". If the user haven't successfully logged in yet, he will have cell in column "Last login" empty.

Also if someone can tell me in comment why is in original query after "MAX(logadm.datum)" the name of the column again "datum" - MAX(logadm.datum) **datum**

Comment: Did you find solution to show all users?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a where statement to your query like so:

```
SELECT username as name,MAX(logadm.datum) LastLogin
FROM creds
LEFT JOIN logadm
ON username = user
WHERE prihl = 1
GROUP BY username
```

Also, the `MAX(logadm.datum) datum` is shorthand for `MAX(logadm.datum) AS datum` it is to change the column name to whatever you wish.

**EDIT**

The `MAX(logadm.datum) datum` is NOT unnecessary. Right here it makes it so that the returned data appears as `datum` instead of `MAX(logadm.datum)` for accessibility. If you carelessly remove it, you might break the code using the query.

Comment: I already tried the query with WHERE, it works, but unfortunately it shows only `vasek   2017-06-21 10:50:19` I would like to see all users just like in output of my original query - if they didn't ever successfully logged in, their column "Last login" would be empty (just like "jan" in original output).

Comment: Just remove the `where prihl = 1` and it should be good to go. @sedlv

Comment: Dude the line whre prihl = 1 is the one thing that is different from my original query :))) @BennjoeMordeno

Comment: @FMashiro Thank for answering my secondary question. It didn't work on page without the second "datum", but in phpmyadmin the sql query without second "datum" works, I just tried that :P

Comment: I realized that I didn't specify clearly, that I want to show all users also. I edited my original post and corrected it.